# How to export cells with links, when saving to a csv?

Tags: excel, libreoffice

I am trying to export an Excel file (`.xlsx`) to a csv, with LibreOffice. Some columns have hyperlinks, which I can open when the sheet is open in LibreOffice. The cell does not show the link, but a short summary text: the link is somehow a property of the cell (or the text, not sure).

I would like that the CSV contains the links for the affected columns (I don't care about the short summary text), but by doing a "Save As csv" I am losing the links. What can I do?

### EDIT

I have investigated a bit: the hyperlink can be manually created in Libreoffice in a cell with `Ctrl-K` or from the menu `Insert -> Hyperlink`. When I try to export the csv, I am offered two relevant options:

[image]

- save cell content as shown
- save cell formulas instead of calculated values

I have played around with them, but those are not helping at all.

Is there any way of exporting the hyperlinks instead of the text?

Comment: @pnuts: a link is just text: `http://...` How can I get that when exporting the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the CSV export filter always saves the link text, not the link URL.  This behavior occurs when saving from LibreOffice format as well, so your question does not need to involve Excel or the .xlsx format.

What I would probably do is write a macro to create a CSV file with the URLs.  If you want to try that, then have a look at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Accessibility/XAccessibleHyperlink.

Depending on what you are trying to do and how much time you are willing to invest, you can [create your own filter](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=3490).

Another option that requires programming would be to use the HTML export filter, which saves both the link text and link URL, and then write some code to parse out the URL.